# Edit form in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new on `reactjs` and I have to update form. I have two `departments`: `name` and `description`. I have to edit the information. If I update only `name` it works, if I update `name` and `description` it works.But when I only update the `description` without updating the `name` then the save button is  disabled. Kindly help me in this issue and following is the code to update form.

When click to update:

```
updatedepartmentState(event) {
    debugger
    const field = event.target.name;
    const value = event.target.value;
    let department = this.state.department;
    department[field] = event.target.value;
    this.setState({department: department}, () => {
    this.validateInput(field, value);
    });
  }
```

This is for saving the record:

```
saveDepartment(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
   if(!this.state.isValidForm) {
     return;
    }
    this.state.department.Id?this.props.actions.update(this.state.department): this.props.actions.saveDepartment(this.state.department);
  }
```

This is for validating data:

```
validateInput(fieldName, value) {
     debugger;
        let {FormErrors, isValidName, isValidDesc} = this.state;
        switch(fieldName) {
            case 'Name':
                  isValidName=(value && ((value.length>1)&&(value.length<50)))&&(customFn.validateRegex(constant.AlphaRegex, value.trim()));
                  FormErrors.Name = isValidName ? '' : 'Invalid Department Name';
            break;
            case 'Notes':
                  isValidDesc=(value && ((value.length>1)&&(value.length<50)))&&(customFn.validateRegex(constant.AlphaRegex, value.trim()));
                  FormErrors.Notes = isValidDesc ? '' : 'Invalid Department Description';
            break;
                default:
            break;
        }
        this.setState({FormErrors, isValidName}, this.validateForm);
    }
```

Comment: show your save button in question

Comment: post the jsx part of the code as well. You might have mentioned required on your name input tag. Can't be sure without looking at the code.